# Does the Fabric.js Path Array have a size limit?

Tags: javascript, svg, fabricjs

I am trying to plot a line graph using Fabric.js. The fabric.Path seems the way to go but it stops drawing after 8 segments.

I've tried loops and individually coding each segment and it always stops drawing after 8 segments

```
const canvas = Controller.Canvas;

line = new fabric.Path('M 90 104', { stroke: 'black', fill: '' });
lastLeft = 90;

for (i = 1; i < 20; i++) {
    lastLeft += 20;
    line.path[i] = ['L', lastLeft, 104];
}

canvas.add(line);
```

I would expect the code to draw a line of 20 segments. It stops at 8. The canvas is plenty large enough.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the fabric.js code, Line's `path` property is not really supposed to be modified like that - it's more of an internal property. After the path is parsed from the path data passed into the constructor, fabric calculates the Line's dimensions and position, which it then uses during a render call. This means that if you've modified `path` *after* constructor is run, you're going to end up with wrong dimensions, hence the missing lines, etc.

There is a way to make fabric re-calculate dimensions, although it uses a private call. Which means that it could change between fabric versions (the snippet below works with 3.4.0) and is therefore not recommended, unless you really want to mess with `path` for some reason:

```js
const canvas = new fabric.Canvas('c')
const initialX = 10
const initialY = 10
const line = new fabric.Path(`M ${initialX} ${initialY}`, { stroke: 'black', fill: '' })

for (let i = 1; i < 20; i++) {
    line.path[i] = ['L', initialX + i * 20, initialY + Math.pow(i, 2)]
}
/* WARNING: Hacky stuff start */
fabric.Polyline.prototype._setPositionDimensions.call(line, {})
/* Hacky stuff end */

canvas.add(line)
```

```css
body {
  background: ivory;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fabric.js/3.4.0/fabric.min.js"></script>
<canvas id="c" width="500" height="400"></canvas>
```